# Tomcat не видит драйвер JDBC MS SQL

Tags: java, веб-программирование, jsp, maven, tomcat

В maven-проекте, запускаемом из NetBeans 8.2 подключена зависимость

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.0.jre10</version>
</dependency>
```

В сервлете вызывается код

```
Connection con = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(url);
```

И дальше идет код работы с таблицами и т.д. Со строкой соединения все в порядке. В обычном java-приложении все работает, а в веб-приложении Tomcat 8 выдает ошибку "No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver:...". Если перед вызовом getConnection() поставить

`Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");`

то Tomcat выдает ошибку 500 с вот таким текстом:

java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerDriver has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 54.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0 (unable to load class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы скорее всего запускаете под java 8, а библиотека jre10.
Попробуйте или запускайть приложение под java 10 или используйте версию драйвера jre8

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file

- Java SE 10 = 54
- Java SE 8 = 52

Comment: Точно! Именно так и было и теперь работает с драйвером 8 ))